# Speeding up DataGridView Cell Content Centering Using DefaultCellStyle

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, centering

It seems that invoking column-based assignment to center contents of all cells in DataGridView is quite slow.  For example, using the following code is quite slow:

```
For j As Integer = 0 To UBound(columnheaders) - 1
  datagridview1.Columns(j).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
  datagridview1.Columns(j).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
Next
```

If the above code is commented out the DataGridView loads much faster, but cell entries aren't centered.  Thus, is there a workaround that's much faster?

Comment: I'm curious what the performance is without the SortMode just to make sure it is the Alignment issue?

Also, the problem might also be DefaultCellStyle not being initialized yet. If I remember correctly, DefaultCellStyle might be null, but when you try to set something to it, it looks up the hierarchy for a CellStyle to grab. So there might be lag due to it working up the chain to get a starting style.

Comment: I did isolate that the slower processing was due to the centering of cells and not the setting for sort order.  Interestingly, the centering syntax used seems to truly involves centering the data via iterative looping. My gut feeling is that by now MS would have developed some sort of behind the scenes way of invoking cell alignment when the data are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a little digging inside the .Net reference source, and I'm 95% sure your issue is the DefaultCellStyle is an expensive operation. If all of your columns are going to have the same exact CellStyle, you try grabbing it once for the 1st column and then doing an assignment on the remain columns.

Just fyi, here is the DefaultCellStyle property that the DataGridViewColumn uses:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewBand.cs,f93400c6fe8a705f

```
    public virtual DataGridViewCellStyle DefaultCellStyle
    {
        get
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle dgvcs = (DataGridViewCellStyle)this.Properties.GetObject(PropDefaultCellStyle);
            if (dgvcs == null)
            {
                dgvcs = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                dgvcs.AddScope(this.DataGridView, 
                    this.bandIsRow ? DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Row : DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Column);
                this.Properties.SetObject(PropDefaultCellStyle, dgvcs);
            }
            return dgvcs;
        }
        set
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle dgvcs = null;
            if (this.HasDefaultCellStyle)
            {
                dgvcs = this.DefaultCellStyle;
                dgvcs.RemoveScope(this.bandIsRow ? DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Row : DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Column);
            }
            if (value != null || this.Properties.ContainsObject(PropDefaultCellStyle))
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value.AddScope(this.DataGridView, 
                        this.bandIsRow ? DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Row : DataGridViewCellStyleScopes.Column);
                }
                this.Properties.SetObject(PropDefaultCellStyle, value);
            }
            if (((dgvcs != null && value == null) || 
                (dgvcs == null && value != null) || 
                (dgvcs != null && value != null && !dgvcs.Equals(this.DefaultCellStyle))) && this.DataGridView != null)
            {
                this.DataGridView.OnBandDefaultCellStyleChanged(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is complex logic going into getting / setting the DefaultCellStyle.

Btw, how are you constructing the DataGridView? If you are using the Visual Studio Form Designer, there is a way to set such things like a DefaultCellStyle that all Columns will inherit from directly, or setting a CellStyle on individual columns directly in the Designer - along with Sort mode, which by the way, I could be wrong, but I think 'Automatic' is the default Sort mode.

Comment: I fill a Data Table (DT), add column names to the DT, then bind the DGV to the DT as a data source, which is a faster way to fill a DGV.  For each row in the DT, I also fill an array (row vector) with cell data, and then simply add each row.  Nothing is used to loop through cell contents via (row,column) positions, which would be horrendously slow.   That reference code looks like a lot of work, and in fact appears to hit each cell in the DGV.  There has to be a faster way to center data?

Comment: Well if you are using a DataTable, there's two ways to approach it: don't define anything on the DataGridView, allowing the DataTable to generate the Columns as it sees fit, or NOT, and instead define all the DataGridViewColumns on the DataGridView. The former allows for late binding, the latter requires early binding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments. I set `AutoGenerateColumns = True` for the DGV, and when binding to the DT using e.g. `myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable`, everything is populated very rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

I found what appears to be a one-step solution, which assigns centering to the entire DataGridView with one line of syntax:

C#:

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

VB.NET

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

The processing time is also significantly shorter than looping through each column, like many forum posts describe.  Originally, I did notice mention of the `RowsDefaultCellStyle` command in several posts, but the `.Alignment` property was not used or provided.

I also set the above command right after definig the DGV, as in:

```
Dim datagridview1 As New DataGridView
datagridview1.Visible = False
datagridview1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

which invokes column centering before data are fetched from the DT.

Comment: Suggesr reading: [Cell Styles in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Thx, saw that earlier today, but I enjoyed more the MS Best Practices page for scaling DataGridViews to larger data sets:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8